# How can I link to an anchor tag that doesn't exist until the Javascript has created it?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page that has a set of `<div>` elements, and each one has an anchor tag associated with it. It looks something like this:

```
<a name="anchor-0"></a>
<div id="div0">Some stuff</div>
<a name="anchor-1"></a>
<div id="div1">More stuff</div>
<a name="anchor-2"></a>
<div id="div2">Yet more stuff</div>
```

The problem is that this set of `<div>` and `<a>` tags are generated by Javascript, and so they don't exist until after the page has been created. When I create a link like this:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/mypage.html#anchor-2
```

... it loads the page but does not jump to the `anchor-2` position, which is only created some time after the browser has had time to execute the Javascript that generated it.

How can I get the browser to move to the selected anchor tag position once the Javascript has generated them?

---

Here is essentially what the Javascript that is generating the HTML looks like:

```
function init() {
  gapi.client.setApiKey('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
  gapi.client.load('blogger', 'v2', function() {
    var request = gapi.client.blogger.posts.list({
      'blogId': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      'fields': 'items(content,title)'
    });
    request.execute(function(response) {
    var main = document.getElementById("main");
    var anchor = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++)
      {
        var Div = document.createElement("div")
        $(Div).append(response.items[i].title);
        $(main).append(Div);
        anchor = document.createElement("a");
        anchor.name = "anchor-" + anchor;
        anchor = anchor +1;

      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: You will have to scroll to that position with JavaScript.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollIntoView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after creation of element, you could do:

```
location.hash = "#anchor-2";
```

or using [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollIntoView)

```
element = document.getElementById('your_element-id');
element.scrollIntoView();
```

get the hash value from url, by doing something like::

```
var hashVal = window.location.hash.substr(1);
//then jump to that hash
location.hash = "#" + hashVal;
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, but I'm not sure how to implement what you are saying. In either case, how do I know which element is the one to scroll to?

Comment: @DaveMG as you mentioned you wanted to jump to "anchor-2", but showing some js code would help..

Comment: I've added the relevant Javascript to the question.

Comment: @DaveMG you could try doing location.hash = "#anchor-2"; after your for loop ends

Comment: But it isn't always `#anchor-2` that a user is going to. A user may be coming to the page having clicked a link for any of the anchor tags. How do I determine which one the user is coming for, and then send them to the selected anchor?

Comment: Nice. Worked like a charm. Thanks for all your help!